# What is so special about C*-Algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras

Could anyone give me a brief explanation about C*-algebras and why they are so important in modern mathematics? I am specially interested in the way C*-algebras are intertwined with the Gelfand-Naimark duality.